# new column creation in existing table and updating the column using python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

Here I am trying to compare a table with 2 tables with millions of records,so i want to compare dem separately and create a separate column in the main table"tabl" name status so that i can update in that itself

*Step*: create a new column in the main table next to email name "status"

*step2*: that column must be updated on comparison with the tab1,tab2 tables

```
list_of_tables=['tab1','tab2'] 
for tab in list_of_tables:
    cursor.execute("select main.*,if({}.email is not null ,'MATCH','NONMATCH') stataus from main left join {} on main.email={}.email".format(tab,tab,tab))
     data_2 = cursor.fetchall()
     print data_2
     data3=list(data_2)
     data_3=pd.DataFrame(data3)
     upload(ftp,data_3,FILEPATH)

def upload(ftp,data_3,FILEPATH):
    data_4=data_3.to_csv(Out_file,index=False,header=None)


main:

email
abc@gamil.com
xyz@email.com
ijk@gmail.com
ghi@gmail.com
pqr@gmail.com
yup@gmail.com
tab1:

email
ijk@gmail.com
yup@gmail.com
tab2:

email
xyz@email.com
pqr@gmail.com
```

**required result**

```
email           valid
abc@gamil.com   non-match
xyz@email.com   match
ijk@gmail.com   match
ghi@gmail.com   non-match
pqr@gmail.com   match
yup@gmail.com   match

but getting like dis:

abc@gamil.com       non-match
xyz@email.com       non-match
ijk@gmail.com       match
ghi@gmail.com       non-match
pqr@gmail.com       non-match
yup@gmail.com       match
abc@gamil.com       nonmatch
xyz@email.com       match
ijk@gmail.com       nonmatch
ghi@gmail.com       nonmatch
pqr@gmail.com       nonmatch
yup@gmail.com       nonmatch
```

Comment: Before asking the same question over and over again, perhaps you might want to try some of the answers in the previous versions of this question first

Comment: yup as the preference was changed now in the previous only comparing and updating all the tables at a time is done but now as to be compared tables have lot of data about millions pefered for doing it seperately...please help me out

Comment: you should still upvote usefull answers and mark as correct the most usefull answer to any question that you post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it finally:

```
data3 = data2.to_sql('main', con=engine, if_exists='replace',index=False)
    cursor.execute("alter table main add status varchar(128) **not null default 'nonmatch**'")
    d=cursor.fetchall()
    print d

    for i in ['tab1','tab3','tab2']:
        cursor.execute("update main **join** {} on main.email={}.email set status=if({}.email is not null,'match','nonmatch')".format(i,i,i))
        conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data3 = data2.to_sql('main', con=engine, if_exists='replace',index=False)
cursor.execute("alter table main add status varchar(128)")
for i in ['tab1','tab2']:
    cursor.execute("update main left join {} on main.email={}.email set status=if({}.email is not null,'match','nonmatch')".format(i,i,i))
    conn.commit()
    data_2=cursor.fetchall()
    data3=data_2
    print data_2
```

the query is fine but i hope so the for loop running is a somewhere wrong as i am getting the last tab2 comparison result only not tab1 and tab2 both comparision result.

Update from Scott Boston:

You can still run:

```
update main left join (select * from tab1 union all select * from tab2) total on main.email=total.email
set status=if(total.email is not null,'match','nonmatch');
```